# Writing a regular expertion for the language $L=\{0^n1^m \mid n\equiv m\pmod 2\}$

Tags: proof-verification, computer-science, automata, regular-language, finite-automata

I need to write a regular expertion for the language of all the binary words that  contains continuum of even number of zeros and **after** that even number of ones *or* odd number of zeros and after that odd number of ones

$L=\{0^n1^m \mid n\equiv m \pmod 2\}$

**My try:**

$(00)^*(11)^*+0(00)^*1(11)^*$

> My attempt is correct?

Comment: This one looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer $(00)^*(11)^*+0(00)^*1(11)^*$ is correct.